# UIScrolllView scroll limit position

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have an UITableView inside an UIScrollView and I want that the user will be able to scroll just when he touches the tableView (I have a map in the background and I want that the user will be able to integrate with the map when the tableView doesn't covers all of it.

I've tried to set scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant to scrollView.contentOffset.y on **-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView** but it didn't work, part of the map is still not touchable. Can anyone give me an advice what should I do? Thanks!

Screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAxby.png)

Comment: Why do u need `UITableView` inside an `UIScrollView`? UITableView is already a subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: Ok try to imagine it :) I have an mapKit and on top of it there is an UITableView, I want that the user will be able to scroll the tableView ontop of the map and hide it so I've put an UIScrollView but than the map wasn't touchable. Do you understand or you need me to send a picture?

Comment: Yes please attach a screenshot as well.

Comment: OK, I have updated the post. Do you understand what i'm trying to do?

Comment: I get it how the table is place on the map, if the scroll view covers the map, the map wont be accessible to touches.

Comment: Exactly, now I want the scrollView's height will be equal to the tableView's Y coordinate and then the map will recive touches, but I've tried to set scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant to scrollView.contentOffset.y but it didn't work, do you have aby idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I understand what you're trying to do. Here is the solution I have come up with. Let me know if this works for you or not.

First off, you need to set the `contentInset` of the table view in your view controller (or if it's possible in the storyboard, set it there. Not sure if it is though?). It's a simple one-liner in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:`, like so:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(400.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
```

The 400.f is just saying start the table view's content 400 points from the top. You can set it to whatever number you'd like or, if you know you want it 200 points from the bottom, do something like this:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.view.bounds.size.height - 200.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);
```

With your content situated OK, now you need to create a subclass of UITableView to use as your table view's class. This class should override one method: `hitTest:withEvent:`. You can set which class you're using for your table view in your storyboard (click on the table view, then go to the Identity Inspector), or you can just change it in your view controller if you're not using storyboards.

In the method you're overriding, you're checking to see if where the user has touched the screen is above the `contentInset` or not (which works for your design). For a more complex design, you'd need some more robust checking.

This should allow the MKMapView to intercept the scroll events from the table view (which is returning nil and disabling scrolling).

Here is the UITableView subclass (you can name it whatever you want):

#### EmbeddedTableView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EmbeddedTableView : UITableView

@end
```

#### EmbeddedTableView.m

```
#import "EmbeddedTableView.h"

@implementation EmbeddedTableView

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (point.y < 0.f) {
        self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    } else {
        self.scrollEnabled = YES;
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: It don't work. Why can't I just change the height of the ScrollView?